# Elastic Beanstalk Alias Without Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have an Elastic Beanstalk (EB) app deployed with a load balancer. In Route53 I defined an alias `myapp.mydomain.com` to point to the EB url. It works fine.
But when I change the EB environment type to 'Single Instance' (from 'Load Balanced'), the alias doesn't work anymore.

Is there a way to use aliases for non-Load-Balanced environments?

Comment: EB url should work whether it is single-instance or load balance. In fact it should be exactly same. Therefore `myapp.mydomain.com` pointing to the EB url should not be affected. Have you observed a change in EB url? Or is your app working when using EB url?

Comment: The app URL is the same and it works (not the alias). 
I have redirected http to https. This is done in the load balancer settings. Not sure if this is the reason it doesn't work when I change the environment to single instance.

Comment: I see. So before you had ssl cert on the ALB? Without ALB, you can't deploy the same cert on the EB instance. Was it ssl cert from ACM?

Comment: The cert is from ACM and is on `*.mydomain.com`. The https setup is in the Load Balancer section of the EB. If I choose single instance, this section is not accessible, so in this case where can I set the https?

Comment: I will make an answer with some details in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments.

The issue is caused by **ACM SSL certificate**. On the load balanced EB environment, the SSL certs are deployed on the ALB. This provides HTTPS capability for your environment.

Single-instance EB environments don't have any load balancer. Thus you have to provide SSL certificates directly on your EB instance. However, **ACM ssl certificates can't be used** on instances.

To rectify the issue you have **two options**:

- Put CloudFront distribution in front of your EB: [Using Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudfront.html). On the CF distro you can install your ACM ssl certificates. The problem is that you will have the following setup:

```
client----HTTPS (ACM SSL cert)---->CF----HTTP---->EB
```

As you see, between CF and your EB instance you will have **HTTP traffic**, which may be not desired. To fix that you can't use self-signed certificates nor ACM cert. You need a **public** ssl certificate from a third party, such as free https://letsencrypt.org/.

This brings us to the second option:

- Install new public certificate on your instance directly. ACM ssl certs can't be used on the instances. You need new one from a third party. A popular choice is https://letsencrypt.org/. You would have to configure **nginx** on the EB instance to serve the ssl certificate; and subsequently, provide you HTTPs capabilities.

Using this option you would have:

```
client----HTTPS (third party SSL cert)---->EB
```